# Leasing Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I am working on an Amortized Loan Calculator to get the Monthly Payment that is being sold.

I know that the formula to calculate Amortized Rate is

P=A/{[(1+R)^N]-1}/[R(1+R)^N]

Where

- A = is the total financed
- R = Periodic Interest Rate - ((Rate / 100) / How often the loan interest compounds)
- N = Term in Months
- P = Payment

In my use case the interest will compound monthly so R will be ((Rate / 100) / 12)

But my problem is that I need to be able to factor in advanced payments into the loan.

For example, the lessee agrees to the loan, but will be making 2 payments (first and last) up front. So they would only be responsible for 58 months after that and the first payment would not be due until a month after the loan originates. So obviously this would factor out the interest and Amortization just a bit differently.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: The situation is not clear to me. What do you mean by "...but will be making 2 payments (first and last) up front" Do you mean that you make 58 payments **at the end** of the month and 2 payments 
**at the beginning** of the month?

Comment: What I meant by that is there will be 2 payments made in advance of the loan. So lets say you have a 60 month Term loan, you make 2 in advance, so you are responsible to pay 58 months now. You would only be making 1 payment per month.

Comment: First of all the formala should be $P=\frac{R\cdot (1+R)^N}{(1+R)^N-1}$. This is not what you´ve posted.

Comment: Beside this, the equation is $$(A-2P)\cdot (1+R)^N=P\cdot \left((1+R)+(1+R)^2+\ldots +(1+R)^{N-2}\right)$$ You see that on the right side there are $N-2-1+2=N-2$ payments only. The two missing payments are the first and the last one. They are made at the beginning.

Comment: Any reply, Ryan?

Comment: Sorry I was out. I am not sure about your formula. Lets use for example, an Amortized Loan of 25,000 for 60 months at an APR of 6% with 2 payments made up front. Given the formula you posted your P would equal .02 cents. I have done the math on a purchased calculator and the value we are looking for is $478.61. My only problem is I do not know the formula used to derive that answer.

Comment: So you make 2 payments immediately and the 58 payments? If yes, the result can be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2825000-2*P%29*%281%2B0.06%2F12%29%5E57%3DP*%5Csum_%28k%3D0%29%5E%2857%29+%281%2B0.06%2F12%29%5E%28k%29), which is $\$476.28$ To make the problem more clear you can post a timeline.

Comment: A crucial information is if a payment is made at the beginning of the month or at the end of the month.

Comment: Yes, you would make 2 payments immediately and then 58 months. So in reality your loan is only 58 months long. Thats where my problem is unfortunately, I am not sure if the calculator that is currently being used is calculating interest at the beginning or the end of the month which I do know would make a difference. The only thing I know is that the output comes to 478.61 when I use all those inputs, which is the input that I need to be taking a way. For context, I am trying to build an application for a calculator that we use externally that is a bit clunky.

Comment: The closest I've come was with my original formula P=A/{[(1+R)^N]-1}/[R(1+R)^N] but with the final N you subtract the advance payments. So it would be P=A/{[(1+R)^N]-1}/[R(1+R)^(N -2)]. Which came out to 478.65 I was hoping it was coming down to a rounding error, but no matter which set of decimals/rounding I used I wasn't able to come up with 478.61

Comment: If I run your wolframAlpha formula like this - [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2825000-2*P%29*%281.005%29%5E58%3DP*%5Csum_%28k%3D0%29%5E%2857%29+%281.005%29%5E%28k%29) - I come up just 5 cents short. I'm curious if it has to do with where we would be subtracting the additional payments in the term?